# How to get text from image python in ubuntu

Tags: python, tesseract

I want to read the text from an image and i use pytesseract in Python.When I run the code:

```
`   


        # Recognize the text as string in image using pytesserct 
        text.append(str(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(imagefilename), encoding='utf-8', errors="Error")))
         #Finally, write the processed text to the file. 
    f.write(" ".join(text)) 

    # Close the file after writing all the text. 
    f.close()
    break`
```

this is the error:

```
    File "/home/doc/desktop/lettura_pdf.py", line 87, in <module>
    text.append(str(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(imagefilename), encoding='utf-8', errors="Error")))
TypeError: image_to_string() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'
```

Comment: Looks like it does not like the 'encoding' argument. Check the function documentation

Comment: The syntax is ' str(object, encoding=encoding, errors=errors) '

Comment: Ok, but you're passing `encoding` argument to `image_to_str()` function. Verify your '()' then.

Comment: Done but i have this error message TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)

Comment: Show your updated code

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
   f = open(txtfile, "w") 
    text = []
    # Iterate from 1 to total number of pages 
    for i in range(1, filelimit + 1): 

        # Set filename to recognize text from 
        # Again, these files will be: 
        # page_1.jpg 
        # page_2.jpg 
        # .... 
        # page_n.jpg 
        imagefilename = folder+"/page_"+str(i)+".jpg"

        # Recognize the text as string in image using pytesserct 
        text.append(str(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(imagefilename)),encoding='utf-8',errors="Error"))
         #Finally, write the processed text to the file. 
    f.write(" ".join(text)) 

    # Close the file after writing all the text. 
    f.close()
    break
```